# How to assign a value to an array from a combobox

Tags: vb.net

The code I have is:

```
Dim Dbase() As String = Nothing

Dbase(0) = Db_ComboBox.Text
```

I have declared `Dbase` as array and assigned `Nothing`, `Db_ComboBox` is a combobox.

For that assignment statement, I'm getting the following error: "**Reference 'Dbase' has a value of 'Nothing'**"

What is the reason for this error, and how can I take the value from the combobox and save it in the array?

Comment: Note that with `vb.net` an array type is defined as `Dim Dbase As String()` and not `Dim Dbase() as String`.

Comment: @ja72: Actually, VB.NET supports both notations.

Comment: I forgot they Nerfed VB.NET after `VS2003` allowing this type of confusion and having default instances in forms. This notation makes only sense when you need to define fixed arrays like `Dim Dbase(100) as String`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at your code:

```
Dim Dbase() As String = Nothing

Dbase(0) = Db_ComboBox.Text
```

Especially the first line. That first line creates a variable that *can* refer to an array, but the `= Nothing` portion explicitly tells it, "Do not create a real array here yet". You have, effectively, a pointer that doesn't point to anything.

I get here that what you really need is a List collection that you can append to over time:

```
Dim Dbase As New List(Of String)()
Dbase.Add(Db_ComboBox.Text)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this:

```
Dim Dbase() As String = Nothing
```

to this (declare an array of 1 element):

```
Dim Dbase(0) As String
```

And then this line will work:

```
Dbase(0) = Db_ComboBox.Text
```

If you need to change your array size you can use [Redim or Redim preserve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), as required.

If you anticipate contents of `Dbase` to change often, I am all with @Joel's suggestion about switching to `List(Of String)` instead of handling array sizes manually.

Answer (score 0):

`Dbase()` IS NOTHING. Look at this example:

```
cargoWeights = New Double(10) {}
atmospherePressures = New Short(2, 2, 4, 10) {}
inquiriesByYearMonthDay = New Byte(20)()() {}
```

That's how you declare arrays.

More examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wak0wfyt.aspx